# Problema com bibliotecas GDB

Tags: gdb

Pessoal estou tentando debugar um código mas meu gdb tá bugado. Ele trava sempre que executa algo de uma biblioteca seja um printf,malloc. Não é problema do código. Já desinstalei o gcc e o gdb e instalei de novo e o programa continua.

As mensagens que recebo:

> at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:24
>   24    ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: Arquivo ou
>   diretório não encontrado. (gdb)  25   in
>   ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S

ou por exemplo:

> __printf (format=0x40342c "%s    if:%s %s\n") at printf.c:28 28   printf.c: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado. (gdb)  32    in
>   printf.c (gdb)  33    in printf.c

Alguma sugestão de como resolver?
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Voce nao esta tentando entrar dentro dessas bibliotecas com o comando `step`? Tenta dar o comando `next` ao invez de usar o `step` para nao entrar em todas as chamadas de funcoes e ve se funciona.